# Diophantine eqution with odd prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

HOW to find all possible set of solutions of an equation type

$y^p \pm 2 = x^2$, where $p$ is any odd prime

High regards to one and all

Comment: I just learned how to solve it when $p$ is $3$ this week. I don't think it is easy in general.

Comment: @Gamamal! well, could you explain when p = 3. May be your method for p =3 will help to solve the other cases.

Comment: We used algebraic number theory. We looked at the equation in $\mathbb Q (\sqrt {-2}) \cap A$

Comment: @Gamamal! WELL, I NEED MORE EXPLANATION.

Comment: Shouting will not help.

Comment: We have $3^3-2=5^2$.

Comment: @Lucian! this is the only solution?

Comment: @rosymilton: It is the only known solution. I don't recall whether its uniqueness has already been proven or not.

Comment: @Lucian! how did you approached in order to get such solution? could you explain please.

Comment: @rosymilton: I didn't. Other people did. It's one of these famous (and possibly open ?) problems in number theory, similar to [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture).